# Bluetooth Module Normal and Standby Mode configuration

Tags: pullup, pulldown

I am using a BT module that can be pulled high for normal mode and pulled low for standby mode. The I/O pin 26 is connected to the MCU GPIO.

Theory of Operation:

When BT_WKUP = 0 --> BT module goes to standby mode
When BT_WKUP = 1 --> BT module goes to normal mode
Default-->BT modules is in standby mode

Are there any suggestions to improve this implementation? [image]

Comment: That's a problematically open-ended question.  Is there a specific concern you have with this?  You haven't stated a theory of operation justifying why you did things this way, it's easy to guess and conclude something reasonable, but Stack Exchange sites are about *specifics* - this isn't a place to come for a general "stamp of approval" - if you have a specific question, state it.   Otherwise, consider that component values are something you can change after you fabricate the board, and both a zero ohm jumper and nothing installed at all are within the range of "change".

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am new to this platform, still in learning phase!

Theory of Operation:

When BT_WKUP = 0 --> BT module goes to standby mode
When BT_WKUP = 1 --> BT module goes to normal mode
Default-->BT modules is in standby mode

Comment: That says nothing about your circuit.